# Problems attempting to upload image to Twitter via POST in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, twitter, upload, oauth, sinatra

I'm using [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) 1.2.6 in Ruby 1.8.7 and I have something like a Twitter client that I'm writing. I am using the [Twitter gem](http://twitter.rubyforge.org/) version 1.7.2 written by John Nunemaker. For database ORM I'm using [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) 3.29.0.

Overall, things are working great. I've got a good Oauth sequence working and any user who goes through the Oauth process can post Tweets to my application.

I cannot however for the life of me get media upload working using update_with_media. I'm trying to upload a multi-part octet-stream image file, keep it in memory and then give it to Twitter.

```
post '/file_upload' do
  user_name = params[:user]
  if params[:action] == "FILE-UPLOAD"
    unless params[:name].match(/\.jpg|png|jpeg/).nil?

          #Assume these 3 lines work, and properly authorize to Twitter
      current_user = User[:user_name => user_name, :current_account => "1"]
      client = current_user.authorize_to_twitter #Handles the Oauth keys/process
          client.update("Text status updates work properly") 

          #Something incorrect is happening in the next two lines. 
          #I'm either handling the file upload wrong, or posting wrong to Twitter
      datafile = params[:file]
      client.update_with_media("File upload from Skype: ", datafile)
      return "File uploaded ok"
    end
  end
end
```

Yet, when I try this, I'm getting:

```
Twitter::Unauthorized - POST https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json: 401: Could not authenticate with OAuth.
```

Its saying the line causing this error is the client.update_with_media line.

I am trying to use [Rack::RawUpload](https://github.com/newbamboo/rack-raw-upload), but I don't know if I'm using it incorrectly. If I don't need to use it I won't, but I'm just currently stuck. The only thing outside of this code snippet that's using it is this at the top of my code:

```
require 'rack/raw_upload'
use Rack::RawUpload
```

Any help on this would be massively appreciated. I've tried messing around with Tempfile.new() as well, but that didn't seem to help much, and I was either getting 401 or 403 errors. I'm fairly new to Ruby, so being as explicit as possible about changes needed would be really helpful.

I should note that I'd like to avoid putting the file on the filesystem if possible. I'm really just passing along the upload here, and I never need access in my scenario to the file on-disk afterward. Keeping the files in-memory is much preferred.

Comment: Does your twitter application have the right permission set for uploading images?

Comment: maybe a stupid question, but is raw_upload the right thing for doing a multipart POST upload?

Comment: Does your code work at all if you just upload media from a simple script? (As opposed to a Sinatra app). Regarding Rack::RawUpload (of which I'm author), I'd say you first try without it to simplify things, with a normal file upload. Only then add it for bells&whistles.

Comment: @djd - I'm not sure actually. That could certainly be the issue. I wasn't aware of the potential of different permissioning levels for Twitter apps, but there very well may be. I'm looking into that now.

Comment: @pablobm - I'm going to try that and see if I can just load a file from the filesystem and send it to Twitter. That should illustrate which side of the fence the problem is on.

Comment: @djd - I've confirmed via doing that upload to Twitter works with a static file, loaded via File.new(). Must be some way I'm dealing with the multipart upload still.

Comment: @pablobm - I've confirmed via doing that upload to Twitter works with a static file, loaded via File.new(). Must be some way I'm dealing with the multipart upload still. Is there a good way to confirm that RawUpload is working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check how your library HTTP headers are setup and logically connected to the POST method you have written here. The thing is that for upload_with_media, twitter api in this gem version requires you to use http://upload.twitter.com upload endpoint instead of the default api endpoint.
The gem may be forcing the api site so while the OAuth based status update works fine, it crashes when you try it with an image. You will need to check the gem documentation to figure out how to force the upload twitter site into the HTTP headers for this method.

Alternatively, consider updating to the latest twitter gem. This is what I got from http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter

> The Twitter::API#update_with_media method no longer uses the custom upload.twitter.com endpoint, so media_endpoint configuration has been removed. Likewise, the Twitter::API#search method no longer uses the custom search.twitter.com endpoint, so search_endpoint configuration has also been removed.

Comment: This is with older API. in v1.1, the url is api.twitter.com. Even i am using twitter gem, and facing the same error.

When i try to send a file, it shows "Could not authenticate you".

It seems, its not sending the authorization/authentication parameters while posting this request.

See this, https://github.com/sferik/twitter/issues/306